# JavaScript - Problem with "this" inside class events when creating more than 1 obj

Tags: javascript, html, css, class, events

I'm new here and I'm creating a new program, but I'm really stuck in this problem.

I created a class that dynamically creates DOM elements and set events to then. The problem is that the "this" reference is not working well.

When I create just one object it works fine, but if I create more all the objects always get the reference from the last.

Both objects should show their own name by clicking.

Can anybody please help me to understand that?

```js
obj = function(name, box){
 this.name = name;
  this.inside = box;
}

obj.prototype = {
 
   start: function() { 
   document.getElementById(this.inside).innerHTML = "<div ID='" + this.name +"_div'>Click me "+ this.name +"<div>";
  },
   
   addClickevent: function(){
   that = this;
    document.getElementById(this.name +"_div").addEventListener("click", function(e){
     alert(that.name);
    }); 
   }
}


x1 = new obj('a','div1');
x1.start();
x1.addClickevent();

x2 = new obj('b','div2');
x2.start();
x2.addClickevent();
```

```html
<div id="div1">

</div>

<div id="div2">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you need global variable `that`? Looks like you miss `var`/`let` in first line of addClickevent. Just replace `that=this` with `let that=this`

Answer (score 0):

"that" is not a keyword in javascript , you have to declare that using let or var for it to work properly.

```js
obj = function(name, box) {
  this.name = name;
  this.inside = box;
}

obj.prototype = {

  start: function() {
    document.getElementById(this.inside).innerHTML = "<div ID='" + this.name + "_div'>Click me " + this.name + "<div>";
  },

  addClickevent: function() {
    let that = this;
    document.getElementById(this.name + "_div").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      alert(that.name);
    });
  }
}
x1 = new obj('a', 'div1');
x1.start();
x1.addClickevent();

x2 = new obj('b', 'div2');
x2.start();
x2.addClickevent();
```

```html
<div id='div1'></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```